# How to call api with delay until response is ok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Need some code recommendations. I need to call api which run some proccess on service.
First response show that proccess is begin and need to check each minute is proccess completed calling api. Now I just call Thread.Sleep before each request, this way quick but dirty. how can i improve the code?

```
// call api, that run some process. it`s long operation which can take up to 15 minutes

boolean isDone = false;

Response<?> proccessRunResponse = execute(request());
    
// if sucess, operation started successfully

if(proccessRunResponse.isSuccess()) {
// now i need to check status each minute and then retry operation(run proccess req, check status) if the process is complete
            
    while (!isDone) {
                
    waitUntilIsDone()

    // request for check status that need to call until response is comleted

    Response<?> status = execute(getRequestForCheckStatus());

    ResponceWrapper res = (ResponceWrapper) status;
    // status can be: in progess, queued etc.. 
    if (res.isComplete()) {
    isDone = true;
    // exit loop and retry operation

    }
}
}
        
}

  private void waitUntilTaskDone() throws InterruptedException {
  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, you can use java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture of jdk to finish.   The below is pseudocode to show how to do. You should modify it according to your actual code.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

// invoke request() in asynchronous
        CompletableFuture<Response> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return execute(request());
        });

        // if success:
        cf.thenAccept((result) -> {
            System.out.println("response" + result);
        });
        
       // if fail
        cf.exceptionally((e) -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        });

       // here should do other things
```